# An absolute minima can be considered local?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

**local minimum value of f if  $f(c) \leqslant  f(x)$  when x is near c.**

I have reading comprehension problem...

By the definition above can an absolute minimun also be included as local?

Comment: Yes, every global minimum is also a local minimum.

Comment: Still, when listing local and absolute (a.k.a. global) extrema of a function, it's common practice to list them separately, and not include the global ones in the list of local extrema. This practice is more convenient and less confusing, except it can lead the unwary to think that absolute extrema are not local ones.

Comment: Just to rant a bit, this is not necessarily true according to official Norwegian high school curriculum (or at least the official exam correcting guide, to be used on nationwide exams). Specifically, points the boundary of the domain of the function cannot be considered local extrema because such a point apparently does not have an open neighbourhood around it where the function is defined, and as such, cannot be a local extremum. Rant over. I think all global extrema are also local extrema, the same way all squares are also rectangles.